# Google Maps api not returning all places within bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps

I'm searching for places by keyword within bounds:

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.87965228677778, -80.1950336785298),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.995437713222234, -80.09846764294042)
);
```

In this example I'm searching "hair stylist" http://jsfiddle.net/9Fqjn/2/

And here I'm doing the same search in the official Google maps - [link](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=hair%20stylist%2016950%20west%20dixie%20hwy%20north%20miami%20beach&hl=en&ll=25.938133,-80.128613&spn=0.109448,0.181789&sll=25.942049,-80.203129&sspn=0.875543,1.454315&hq=hair%20stylist&hnear=16950%20W%20Dixie%20Hwy,%20Miami,%20Miami-Dade,%20Florida%2033160&t=m&fll=25.955575,-80.126896&fspn=0.109432,0.181789&z=13)

You'll see that Google Maps returns more results. Why am I not getting all the places in my own map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that by default, each Place search returns up to 20 establishment results per query. [Pagination](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination) is required for more places.